# How to call method of Parent class using Child object in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Parent Class 
   Method name -> calculateTax
Since Child 
  Method name -> calculateTax

class will inherit this method I still want to call parent class calculateTax method

Child ch = new Child()
ch.calculatetax() -> this should call parent class method , how can this be achieved

Comment: If you don't have any other logic in your child class's `calculateTax()`, then think about removing it completely. If you use some data returned from parent, then you could use the super keyword

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, in your case since you are calling  calculateTax method with the object of Child class. The method of child class will override the calculateTax  of parent class.

But you can call the parent class method by using super keyword inside the child method body like:-

```
super.calculateTax ();
```