# Return String of method in one class and pass it as parameter in another class with a same method name

Tags: overriding

I have a String method pet in a parent class that is same in another class and I want to use "Avish" as parameter in other class pet method how it can be do I am stucking in this.

```
class Parent {
    
public String pet()
{
return "Avish";
}}
class Inherit extends Parent    {
public static void main(String s[])
{
            
public String pet(new Inherit().pet()) // this is a method where I want to use Avish as //parameter how can I do that
{
System.out.println();}}}



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IcnE.png
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call method of Parent class using Child object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178665/how-to-call-method-of-parent-class-using-child-object-in-java)

Comment: Actually this option was asking to me in one of the interview question interviewer said to me that you don't have to write a code as you mentioned in your question I know that how to call method of parent class suing child object.. But he wants what you will pass in the method name of second class so that return string of first method will come in the second class method. i.e. how Avish string will pass to the second class method which has same name.